# How can I change File pointer position 4 line back while writing the file using perl?

Tags: perl, file, file-handling, filehandle

I am writing the file using Perl. There is a situation where after writing 4 lines, I have to go back 4 lines and write something then come back to end of file and again start write. Is there any way to move file handle position line wise?

Comment: Re: `Is there any way to move file handle position line wise?` No. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed move the position around using [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html). Files don't have indexes of lines, though, so you'll either have to keep track of the position of lines (as obtained using [`tell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html)) as you write them, or discover them using an approach similar to [File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ReadBackwards)'s.

What do you want to happen to the contents of the file that's between the position to which you seek and the end of the file? You will need to copy it  if you want to insert lines, or [`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) the file if you want to delete it.

If you can, maintain a buffer instead.

```
my @buf;
while (...) {
   if (...) {
      splice(@buf, -4, 0, $line);   # Insert the line 4 lines from the end.
   } else {
      push(@buf, $line);            # Append a line.
   }

   print($fh shift(@buf)) while @buf > 4;
}

print($fh @buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) to do all the magic for you. It [ties](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) a file to an array so each line is represented by an array element. [Tying](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html) is a mechanism that is very powerful, but seems to be considered very advanced<sup>1</sup> nowadays.

That makes it possible to use normal array operations like [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) and [`unshift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html) or even [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) on the file. You don't need to put newlines. It uses `$/` automatically.

```
use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'foo.txt' or die $!;

push @file, "Line 1";
push @file, "Line 2";
push @file, "Line 3";
push @file, "Line 4";
push @file, "Line 5";

# to overwrite
$file[-4] = 'Line 6 overwrote line 2';

# to append
$file[-3] .= ' and Line 7';

# to insert
splice @file, -2, 0, 'Line 8';
```

The file will now contain:

```
Line 1
Line 6 overwrote line 2
Line 3 and Line 7
Line 8
Line 4
Line 5
```

---

<sup>1) I say *advanced*, but really I mean that it is not widely spread or understood nowadays. There are not a lot of learning materials that cover `tie`, and the original use-case of database file access is quite dated and. I would say a lot of people have never heard of it, though it's a powerful feature.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it advanced, as much as something that is (almost?) unique to perl. So means you have people who don't really understand the concept.

Comment: @Sobrique I chose the word _advanced_ since it's hardly covered in modern learning resources, and there are not a lot of common use cases. I agree that it's rather unique, though I do remember seeing a talk recently where someone said that a couple newer language now have a similar feature, and that we've had it for a long time. But I can't recall where that was, or which languages.

Comment: No, true enough. With OO being commonplace - and generally a better understood paradigm - the need for `tie` is diminished. And arguably, it's a bit hazardous to have a 'magic' thing that looks like a normal variable.

Comment: Tie::File is almost always an abysmal solution. You're better off reading the entire file into memory. It will use less memory and be incredibly faster

Comment: Advanced seems an appropriate term. It's on par with operator overloading which is an advanced topic